# How to install openshift-ansible version 3.10 on Centos 8

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, openshift-origin, okd

Can anybody let me know how to install openshift-ansible in Centos 8.2.2004 ? I have installed '**centos-release-openshift-origin310**' in my Centos 8 VM but when I am running ' **yum install openshift-ansible**' or '**dnf install openshift-ansible**', I am getting the following error message ----

```
[root@openshift1 vars]#
[root@openshift1 vars]#
[root@openshift1 vars]# dnf install openshift-ansible
Last metadata expiration check: 2:03:24 ago on Sun 26 Jul 2020 08:17:56 PM IST.
Error:
 Problem: cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - nothing provides python-six needed by openshift-ansible-3.10.68-1.git.0.f908cf5.el7.noarch
  - nothing provides libselinux-python needed by openshift-ansible-3.10.68-1.git.0.f908cf5.el7.noarch
  - nothing provides python-passlib needed by openshift-ansible-3.10.68-1.git.0.f908cf5.el7.noarch
  - nothing provides python2-crypto needed by openshift-ansible-3.10.68-1.git.0.f908cf5.el7.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
[root@openshift1 vars]#
[root@openshift1 vars]#
```

I faced similar situation in installing '**centos-release-openshift-origin311**' but it was also showing python related errors. Hence, I moved to '**centos-release-openshift-origin310**'. Here I have **python3** instead of python.

Ex - The first dependency it shows that it needs '**python-six**' whereas I have already present '**python3-six**' in my environment.

Comment: I simply don't understand if people don't want to answer, then why are they voting to close the question ? If they are not interested in giving responses, then its fine. But I have posted this question because I need a solution to it. If people want to close it, then they should better provide the reason also.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you'll be able to do that (ie run OCP 3.11 on Centos8). As a potential problem I can see is thet in RH8/Centos8 they replaced the usage of iptables by nftables...

And OKD 4.5 is officially out now and the installation (and upgrades) is way easier (No nore ansible playbooks, usage of Fedora Core OS..etc), maybe it's time for an upgrade

[OKD 4.5 install doc on bare metal](https://docs.okd.io/latest/installing/installing_bare_metal/installing-bare-metal.html)